# Back edges program

Tags: python, dictionary, graph, depth-first-search, directed-acyclic-graphs

I implemented a program that finds back edges on a graph stored a dictionary.

Example :

- Input : `(graph={'A': ['B','C'], 'B': ['C'], 'C': ['D'], 'D': ['A']}, start='A')`
- Output : `[('D', 'A'), ('B', 'C')]`

The problem is that it also returns cross edges, can you help me find where the problem is ?
I haven't found an answer for several days.

```py
def ArcA(graph, start):
    stack = []
    discovery_time = {}
    finish_time = {}
    back_edges = []
    time = 0

    stack.append(start)

    while stack:
        current = stack.pop()
        if current not in discovery_time:
            time += 1
            discovery_time[current] = time
            stack.append(current)
            
            for neighbor in graph[current]:
                if neighbor not in discovery_time:
                    stack.append(neighbor)
                elif discovery_time[neighbor] < discovery_time[current]:
                    back_edges.append((current, neighbor))

            time += 1
            finish_time[current] = time

    return back_edges
```

Thank you !

I expect my code to only returns back edges, but I think that it also returns cross edges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64298275/6146136) correctly, then back edges lead to `neighbor`s that are in `stack` at the time, so instead of *`elif discovery_time[neighbor] < discovery_time[current]`*, you need to use **`elif neighbor in stack`**

```py
def ArcA(graph, start):
    stack = []
    discovery_time = {}
    finish_time = {}
    back_edges = []
    time = 0

    stack.append(start)

    while stack:
        current = stack.pop()
        if current not in discovery_time:
            time += 1
            discovery_time[current] = time
            stack.append(current)
            
            for neighbor in graph[current]:
                if neighbor not in discovery_time:
                    stack.append(neighbor)
                elif neighbor in stack: ### EDIT ###
                    back_edges.append((current, neighbor))

            time += 1
            finish_time[current] = time

    return back_edges
```

and now <kbd>`ArcA(graph={'A': ['B','C'], 'B': ['C'], 'C': ['D'], 'D': ['A']}, start='A')`</kbd> should return just **`[('D', 'A')]`** and cross edges like *`('B', 'C')`* should no longer be included in the output.